# Is there a way to find and remove the datetime from multiple rows in Google Sheets?

Tags: regex, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Hope you're doing well.

Imagine I have the following Sheet:

```
5:20:58 xxxx: entro con el mismo xxxx                           
5:21:08 xxxx: xxxx                          
5:21:58 xxxxx: Perfecto, te pido de 5 a 10 minutos mientras 
reviso la configuración de las etiquetas. ¿De acuerdo?                          
5:22:04 xxxxx: ok
```

I need to delete the datetime of all those rows. The result

```
xxxx: entro con el mismo xxxx                           
xxxx: xxxx                          
xxxxx: Perfecto, te pido de 5 a 10 minutos mientras 
reviso la configuración de las etiquetas. ¿De acuerdo?                          
xxxxx: ok
```

Is there a formula in Google Sheets to make this?
I tried with `REPLACE`, `SPLIT` but is not applicable to all the rows in the sheet.

(The real sheet has too many rows, I extracted a part from the sheet to give an example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### EDIT

*(following [OP's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67144436/is-there-a-way-to-find-and-remove-the-datetime-from-multiple-rows-in-google-shee/67144652?noredirect=1#comment118701364_67144652))*

> *...there are sometimes that the data not starts with a timestamp. ... How can I adjust the formula to make it work?*

Please use the following altered formula

```
=INDEX(IFERROR(REGEXEXTRACT(B1:B;" (.*)");B1:B))
```

**OR** *(for an even more robust formula)*

```
=INDEX(IFERROR(REGEXEXTRACT(B1:B;"^\d+:\d+:\d+ (.+)");B1:B))
```

---

### Original answer

Please use the following formula *(adjust range to your needs)*

```
=INDEX(IFERROR(REGEXEXTRACT(B1:B;" (.*)")))
```

**OR** *(depending on your locale)*

```
=INDEX(IFERROR(REGEXEXTRACT(B1:B," (.*)")))
```

[image]

Functions used:

- [`INDEX`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098242)
- [`IFERROR`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093304)
- [`REGEXEXTRACT`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098244)

Comment: Thank you very much! I am a newbie of Google Sheets, I tried your solution and it works perfectly. Honestly, I don´t understand what does the "(.*)" in your formula. I will try to learn the index function and I hope to understand what it does.

Comment: Please have a look [here](https://github.com/google/re2/blob/master/doc/syntax.txt) for further reading on regular expressions. Thank you for taking the time to accept.

Comment: this is wrong as the "reviso" is being omitted by your regex. you can see erik tyler's answer for a better one

Comment: @KokoJumbo The formula works. The image was wrong. Erik's formula also works.

Comment: @marikamitsos if the data only has starting timestamps all over (which is not really clarified from the question above)

Comment: @KokoJumbo *"...not really clarified from the question above"* Maybe true, but clear to the OP and as a result accepted.

Comment: I made some new tests and I would like to clarify that there are sometimes that the data not starts with a timestamp.

I applied the formula and there are information deleted as you can see: https://ibb.co/ZGjqrcJ

How can I adjust the formula to make it work? Thanks @marikamitsos for the articles.

Comment: You have to remember that **regex formulas are based on patterns. The more abstract the data gets, the more cases one needs to cover in the formula.**

Answer (score 1):

Let's say your raw data is in A2:A. Place this in the second cell (e.g., B2) of an otherwise empty column:

`=ArrayFormula(IF(A2:A="",,TRIM(REGEXREPLACE(A2:A,"\d+:\d+:\d+",""))))`

**ADDENDUM:**

Version for some international locales (where semicolon is used in place of a comma within formulas):

`=ArrayFormula(IF(A2:A="";;TRIM(REGEXREPLACE(A2:A;"\d+:\d+:\d+";""))))`

Comment: I tried this but I got an error in the formula. I tried with less data, and its the same.

Comment: Juan, you are likely in Portugal or another local that uses semicolons where the US uses commas within formulas. Please see my edited post above and try the bottom formula.